# Discover filter query does not run in dev-tools

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I get this error while trying to run a query through Dev tools section of Kibana.

> "reason": "[match] query does not support [type]"

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "eventSource": {
        "query": "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the line "type": "phrase" then this query will run without any problem and return 5125 results.

But this query has been auto-generated by the kibana filter and returns 4247 records on dashboard.
I will like to know why "type" is not supported in dev-tools while discover tab has no issues.

Comment: Can you share the exact query that's been generated by Kibana? Are you sure it wasn't a `multi_match` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually [a bug](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/29223) in the DSL generation that [got resolved](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/48033) recently.

If you click on "Inspect" and check the real query being sent, you'll notice that it looks like this

```
    {
      "match_phrase": {
        "eventSource": {
          "query": "s3.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    },
```